# Rendering Error in Sitecore local instance set up

Tags: sitecore

While setting up sitecore in my local instance and trying to access a particular site or a homepage, the error below occurred. PLease help me in solving this issue. Thanks

Rendering exception processing View: /Views/Layouts/AccentureBaseLayout.cshtml : Error while rendering view: '/Views/Layouts/AccentureBaseLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). :

Comment: Please improve tour question with the full error and relevant code from your View that is throwing the error

Comment: Please see erro in logs ERROR Rendering exception processing View: /Views/Layouts/AccentureBaseLayout.cshtml for /?sc_mode=edit
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Layouts/AccentureBaseLayout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Comment: Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Accenture.Online.SitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) in C:\NextGenAcn_Sc_4229\su8main\Accenture.Online\Sitecore\Pipelines\ExecuteRenderer.cs:line 32

Comment: Yes, please put the full lpg in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Also provide the View code which is causing the error (AccentureBaseLayout.cstml)

Answer (score 0):

AccentureBaseLayout.cstml is not the reason here for this error. Below are the steps to find the root cause of this error.

- Goto the line which causes this error in AccentureBaseLayout.cstml
- if this line loads a placeholder then go to the rendering which is being loaded in this placeholder.
- you will find the root cause of the error there. it may be some code issue in your controller. 
  In my case, it was the null model being passed to the view. I fixed that issue and error went away.